# Association from promotion rule to product not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, spree

I'm trying to access products through promotion but can't.

In the command line: Promotion.last.promotion_rules.first.products

Returns an error of an uninitialized constant.

Here are my associations:

```
class Product
   has_many :product_promotion_rules, class_name: 'ProductPromotionRule'
   has_many :promotion_rules, through: :product_promotion_rules
end 

class ProductPromotionRule
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :promotion_rule
end

class PromotionRule
   has_many :product_promotion_rules, class_name: 'ProductPromotionRule', join_table: 'products_promotion_rules', foreign_key: :promotion_rule_id
   has_many :products, through: :product_promotion_rules
   belongs_to :promotion 
end

class Promotion
   has_many :promotion_rules
end
```

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant Promotion::Rules::ProductValue::ProductPromotionRule

Answer (score 0):

Within the Product model try:

```
has_many :product_promotion_rules, class_name: 'ProductPromotionRule', foreign_key: :product_id
has_many :promotion_rules, through: :product_promotion_rules, source: :promotion_rule
```

And within the PromotionRule model:

```
has_many :products, through: :product_promotion_rules, source: :product
```

**Update: saw this, which you may want to remove/fix:**

```
join_table: products_promotion_rules
```

Either change to:

```
join_table: product_promotion_rules
```

Or try removing it.

Comment: Getting the same error... NameError: uninitialized constant Promotion::Rules::ProductValue::ProductPromotionRule